# How can I reuse a contact form in a ViewComponent?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, view-components

I want to use same contact form on multiple pages in my project.

I tried it on a sample project named `FormInViewComponent` as below:

`Controllers` > **`TestController.cs`**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
namespace FormInViewComponent.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

`Views` > `Test` > **`Index.cshtml`** (I called the `ViewComponent` on this page)

```html
@model FormModel
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <h3>Page content is here</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 bg-light p-3">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("SampleForm")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Models` > **`FormModel.cs`**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
namespace FormInViewComponent.Models
{
    public class FormModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`ViewComponents` > **`SampleFormViewComponent.cs`**

```cs
using FormInViewComponent.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
namespace FormInViewComponent.ViewComponents
{
    public class SampleFormViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(FormModel formModel)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(View(formModel));
        }
    }
}
```

`Views` > `Shared` > `Components` > `SampleForm` > **`Default.cshtml`**

```html
@model FormModel
    
<h4>ViewComponent is here</h4>
<b class="text-info">Sample Form</b>
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label><br />
            <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <p class="text-center">
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send" />
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Aside, could you edit your question to include an explanation of what's not working? E.g., are you getting an exception—and, if so, what is it? My assumption, based on your code, is that you're not getting an error, but also that your form is not rendering, since issues with `Component.InvokeAsync()` tend to fail silently. If so, that would be useful for respondents to know. In the meanwhile, I've contributed an answer based on what I'd expect reading through your code.

Answer (score 0):

The most immediate issue is that you're trying to invoke the `SampleFormViewComponent` without any parameters—but your `InvokeAsync()` method requires a `FormModel` parameter. As such, while it may be able to find your `SampleFormViewComponent`, it won't be able to execute `InvokeAsync()`.

#### Passing `FormModel` as a parameter

To remedy this, you *must* pass an instance of a `FormModel` to your `Component.InvokeAsync()` call using the following syntax:

```cs
@await Component.InvokeAsync("SampleForm", new { formModel = new FormModel() })
```

#### Constructing `FormModel` inline

The alternative, depending on your exact requirements, is to remove the `formModel` parameter, and instead construct your view component inside your `InvokeAsync()` method:

```cs
namespace FormInViewComponent.ViewComponents
{
    public class SampleFormViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            var formModel = new FormModel();
            return await Task.FromResult(View(formModel));
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, a view model will usually have data associated with it. You can pull that data from the current context (e.g., from the route parameters or query string), or use that information to lookup data from another location (e.g. a database).

#### Processing your form

This raises another issue, however: How are you expecting to *process* your form? If you're posting it to a separate controller action or e.g. web service, that's no problem. If you're expecting your view component to *also* process the results, as you might in a controller, you're going to run into difficulties. Notably, view components don't provide any type of routing or complex model binding. So while you can *render* the form using a view component, you should *process* the form using a controller or web service.